# Returning a single Eloquent object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this function:

```
protected function compare_something($found_item, $saved_items)
{
foreach($saved_items as item) {

$compare_x = false;
$compare_y = false;
$compare_z = false;

$compare_x = strpos($found_item,$item->x) !== false ? true: false;
$compare_y = strpos($found_item,$item->y) !== false ? true: false;
$compare_z = strpos($found_item,$item->z) !== false ? true: false;

if($compare_x && $compare_y && $compare_z){
return $item;
}

}
return false;
}
```

I expect `$item` to be the object where `$compare_x, $compare_y` and `$compare_z` are true, however this function simply returns the entire eloquent object (`$saved_items`) instead of the compared one.

I am not sure why is this happening. I can always return:

```
$item->id
```

And then do `Item::where("id",$item->id)->first();`

But shouldn't just return `$item` just deliver me the chosen item?

Comment: As a side note, if you have a list of `Eloquent` items, they're stored as a `Collection`, which has a handy `filter()` function: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter (note slight syntax changes based on your version of Laravel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eloquent queries always return a collection, so you can easily use the [`filter`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter) function for this. After that call the [`first`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-first) function to get the first element. If there are no elements in the collection, `null` will be returned.

For example:

```
return $saved_items->filter(function ($item) use ($found_item) {
    return strpos($found_item, $item->x) !== false &&
           strpos($found_item, $item->y) !== false &&
           strpos($found_item, $item->z) !== false;
})->first();
```

Comment: Or, if you were to use `first()` with the same function (instead of `filter()`) you'd get the same outcome. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-first)